# Finding directories inside a folder and deleting if smaller than a certain size?

Tags: command-line, find

What command can I execute to check the directories inside a folder and if the total size of the directory is smaller than 30MB, delete it? I played around with the `find` command trying to move files based in the size but it didn't work properly.

I was using (for 1mb):

```
find . -size +102400k -exec mv DIRECTORY
find . -size -102400k -exec mv DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about *directory* size, I'm not sure `find` is going to help. `du` is going to have to be involved at some point.

Here's something I have written to find near directories under 30M:

```
du --max-depth 1 | awk -v q='"' '$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print q $0 q}'
```

You can then chain that into `xargs rm -rf` but I would test it *very seriously* before doing that. You might want to move the directories (with `mv`) instead of straight-up deleting them.

Comment: Hi Oli, I've tested this command and it just listed all directories ... sorry, I'm not really used with linux commands so maybe I had to  do something else that I'm not aware.

Comment: @DanielGomes You need to stick `| xargs rm -rf` on the end of that command... But as I say, please test the first part thoroughly first.

Answer (score 0):

Find doesn't know the total size of directories. So that approach won't work.

You could find all directories, and exec a script that uses du to see if they are smaller than 1MB.