# Finding directories inside a folder and deleting folder + parent if subdirectory is smaller than a certain size?

Tags: command-line, directory, find, rm, du

I use gmusic to order and organise my folder structure. However this means I am left with some folders that do not have any files other then normally, a image cover.

I would like to sort through all my folders & subfolders and remove the parent folder if say, the folders are under 5mb.

Here is what I can see from [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/116682/115908), but this does not handle sub-folders.

```
du --max-depth 1 | awk -v q='"' '$1 < 30000000 && $2 != "." {sub(/^[0-9\t ]+/, "", $0); print q $0 q}'
```

Below we would want to remove the folder `Always Ascending` and leave all over folders.

[image]

But here, we would want to remove `George Harrison` & `2017 - Guardians Of The Galaxy Vol. 2  Awesome Mix Vol. 2` & `Disk 1`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` all folders, check size is smaller e.g. 5000.
If smaller, `rm -Rf` the folder and use `-prune` to not descend into this folder. The second `-exec` and the `-prune` will run only if the first `-exec` is true.

```
find . -type d \
  -exec sh -c '[ $(du -s "$1" | cut -f1) -lt 5000 ]' find-sh {} \; \
  -exec echo rm -Rf {} \; \
  -prune
```

I put `echo rm`, please double check if the output is correct before removing the `echo`.

Comment: Wow that executed quickly! Thank yuo